# how to downgrade angular-cli 1.7.3 to angular-cli 1.6.8

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I am getting issue in my Ubuntu regarding reinstalling of angular.
my current version:
Angular 1.7.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS: Linux
Angular: 4.4.4

I want to reinstall from angular 1.7.3 to angular 1.6.8

Please help..

Comment: `npm uninstall @angular/cli@1.7.3 -g` then `npm cache clean --force` then `npm install @angular/cli@1.6.8 -g`

Answer (score 7):

Correct command now is this:

`npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install @angular/cli@1.6.8`

The key here is first @ before angular and angular/cli not angular-cli.

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall the current version of angular cli- 1.7.3 and install 1.6.8

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.6.8
```